# Why is the result of string.format() a string, even for numbers?

Tags: python, format

The following evaluates to true:

```
'{:.2f}'.format(2.0) > '{:.2f}'.format(10.0)
```

I want to write a number to excel with two decimals (2 as 2.00) using `dataframe.to_excel`, but it gets displayed as text instead of a number in a  cell.

Update:

```
import pandas as pd

data_table = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,5.0,6.0]]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_table)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='xlsxwriter')
dataframe.to_excel(writer,float_format='%11.2f', index=False)
writer.save()
```

It still shows 6 instead of 6.00. Maybe excel strips the 0 when I open it

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Comment: Why would you expect `str.format()` to produce anything other than a string? And even then, how would rounded numbers (limited to 2 decimals) compare any different than their unrounded counterparts? If you needed close equality, use the `round()` function.

Comment: Excel has formatting options, use those to alter how numbers are displayed. Formatting floats to strings will indeed not work in Excel cells.

Comment: As stated, `str.format()` produces a string. Raw numbers aren't formatted - that's why a formatted number is stored as a string. Besides, doesn't Excel automatically detect cell contents anyway, turning your formatted "number" into a number following Excel's formatting settings?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Excel explicitly converts integers to dates. Or scientific notation. Or Emoji...Or whatever else they determined was a "good idea"

Comment: @That1Guy, the conversion is pretty decent these days. I've only run into problems in trying to get it to recognize a certain date format string as a date (solved with string manipulation formulas within Excel).

Comment: Enough with the downvotes! It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 1):

[to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) has a float_format option.

Comment: The linked documentation says that that option is a "format string for floating point numbers." Sounds like that'll produce a string, won't it?

Comment: No, it'll tell Excel what format specifier to apply when displaying floats.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use `int()` on your result.</strike>

Why String.format Returns a string? It doesn't check if it's a number, and it should be applied on strings only.

EDIT:

Of course, you want that formatting visible in the resulting Excel file.

Use:

```
Dataframe.to_excel(excel_writer, float_format=float_format, **kwargs)
```

whereas **kwargs are your other arguments and float_format is your Format.

This will Format the numbers correctly in your Excel, if you save them as a number

Comment: Casting the formatted string as an integer will discard all the formatting.

Comment: @decontamin4t0R I update my question. I do not know why `float_format='%11.2f'` does not work